# how to get index in *.ftl while iterating list

Tags: jsp, freemarker

i want to get number of item in `*.ftl` of list while iterating it.
it is converted from `*.jsp` to `*.ftl` file.
Please help.thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `<#list foos as foo>...${foo?counter}...</#list>`, if you want it to start with 1. `foo?index` if you want it to start with 0. (See also: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using like:

```
<#list ['A', 'B', 'C'] as x>

    ${x}

</#list>
```

o/p:
A
B
C

If you will use x?index it will return index of element but its count starts from 0 like:

```
<#list ['A', 'B', 'C'] as x>

${x?index}

</#list>
```

o/p:
0
1
2

Comment: <#list ['A', 'B', 'C'] as x>  ${x?index} </#list>

Comment: You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375355/how-to-get-index-in-ftl-while-iterating-list#) to post your comment into it, or revise what you already entered.